# Mostrar imágenes desde un array de String en tableview

Tags: array, string, swift, imagen, tablas

Inserto las imágenes dentro de una carpeta en Xcode y creo el array

```
    let banderas = ["bandera1.png","bandera2.png","bandera3.png","bandera4.png"]
```

Introduzco los datos en la tabla

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomTableViewCell
```

Esto se muestra bien

```
    customCell?.myNameLabel.text = comunidades[indexPath.row]
    customCell?.myInfoLabel.text = infor[indexPath.row]
```

Print -> En cada celda de la tabla muestra la string por consola

```
    print(banderas[indexPath.row])
```

No hay errores pero no se muestra la imagen

```
    customCell?.myImage.image = UIImage.init(named: banderas[indexPath.row])

    return customCell!
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi código funcionaba, el problema estaba en las imágenes, al meterlas en la carpeta se desconectaron del Target Membership:

[image: Target membership]

Simplemente marcándolas volvió a funcionar.

Al introducir la imagen directamente a la UIImageView es cuando me apareció este error y lo pude corregir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Error* Could not load the "imagen" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Answer (score 0):

Cuando trabajas con imágenes no debes de usar el .png:

```
let banderas = ["bandera1","bandera2","bandera3","bandera4"]
```

luego el tema de las celdas lo recomendable debes hacer los siguiente

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}

        let imageItem = banderas[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageItem)
    }
```

no olvidar también lo siguiente

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return banderas.count
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, quitar el .png me ha acortado el código por otro lado la función numberofRows me repetía el array en la tabla.  Muchas gracias por su tiempo.